# Django multi site or multi tenancy?

Tags: django, multi-tenant, python-social-auth

I am using django with python social auth as a way to authenticate users and allow them access to a specific service.
This is working fine, but now I'm faced with the problem of scaling up the solution, having multiple busineses using the solution, each with their own social users and own web templates. Businesses would also have to have django admin interface to see their users and other personal metrics.

I imagine something like:

```
www.mywebpage.com/businessA/business_own_urls
www.mywebpage.com/businessA/admin_url
www.mywebpage.com/businessB/business_own_urls
www.mywebpage.com/businessB/admin_url
www.mywebpage.com/businessC/business_own_urls
www.mywebpage.com/businessC/admin_url
```

I am not sure what initiative to take, and which would be the most apropiate one.
Any help appreciated

Comment: You can run multiple Django servers each with there own database for a specific business, and for instance let nginx do the routing.

Comment: It seems doable but not the optimal way of doing it. Woudln't that be heavy on resources? What about using dajngo.multisite?